# Does this series violate the integral test condition for convergence/divergence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

My professor is asking me to determine if the following series is convergent or divergent using the integral test specifically.

$$
\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}n^2e^{-n}
$$

However, this seems to violate the requirement that $f(x)$ should be decreasing over $[1,\infty)$ since $f(1)<f(2)$. The rest of the function is decreasing over $(2,\infty)$ which makes me think that I'm missing some special trick.

I can't tell if I'm missing something or if my professor just did this on purpose to make sure we check our conditions...

Comment: If you haven't done yet, you should try to prove that $\sum_{n=n_1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent if and only if $\sum_{n=n_2}a_n$ is convergence. In other words, the convergence does not depend on the initial index of the sequence (of course, the sum of the series, when convergent, will depend on that initial index).

Comment: In this particular example where $x^2e^{-x}$ is maximised at $x=2$, you can say $\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}n^2e^{-n}=e^{-1}+4e^{-2}+\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=3}n^2e^{-n} \le e^{-1}+4e^{-2} + \int\limits^{\infty}_{x=2}x^2e^{-x}\, dx < 2.27$.  In fact the series is marginally less than $1.9923$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Convergence depends only on the tail of the series so you can start the integral test at any convenient point and ignore the finite number of terms before that.

Comment: @RonanHoward To clarify what this answer is saying, as long as there is *some* $n$ (not necessarily $1$) such that $f(x)$ is decreasing on $[n, \infty]$, you can use the integral test.